# POST Request Not Affecting HTML Output in localhost server

Tags: python, post, localhost

I have a simple `localhost 0.0.0.0:8000/` server set up which accepts `GET` and `POST` requests. The html in the server is supposed to output `GET!` when a get request is sent and is supposed to output `POST!` when a post request is sent. When a get request is sent the `GET!` gets outputted to the html, but it doesn't with the `POST` request even when I refresh the page.

I attached an image of what the output looks like when I run it in Chrome (where the problem is):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzwc2.png]

The webpage only prints `"GET!"` even with `POST` requests.

It works just fine when I run it in `Postman`, and the html the `Postman` returns does contain `"POST!"` instead of `"GET!"` In `Postman` this is the return I get when I do a post request:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC8HB.png]

I feel like its very simple but I have no idea what is wrong and why the `POST!` wont get outputted to the local server.

**This is the request I send:**

```
import requests

requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:8000/', data={'value':True})
```

**This is the code I use to run the server:**

```
import argparse
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
def _html(self, message):
    """This just generates an HTML document that includes `message`
    in the body. Override, or re-write this do do more interesting stuff.
    """
    content = f"<html><body><h1>{message}</h1></body></html>"
    return content.encode("utf8")  # NOTE: must return a bytes object!

def do_GET(self):
    self._set_headers()
    self.wfile.write(self._html("GET!"))

def do_HEAD(self):
    self._set_headers()

def do_POST(self):
    # Doesn't do anything with posted data
    self._set_headers()
    self.wfile.write(self._html("POST!"))



def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, addr="localhost", port=8000):
    server_address = (addr, port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)

    print(f"Starting httpd server on {addr}:{port}")
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run a simple HTTP server")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-l",
        "--listen",
        default="localhost",
        help="Specify the IP address on which the server listens",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-p",
        "--port",
        type=int,
        default=8000,
        help="Specify the port on which the server listens",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    run(addr=args.listen, port=args.port)
```

Comment: your code has wrong indentations - methods are not inside class - so they may not work.

Comment: how do you send POST in browser ? You would have to use `<form>` to send POST request to server from browser but I don't see HTML with `<form>` in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you tested `POST` request from browser but you would need page wiht `<form method="POST">` to send `POST` request.

If I add `<form>` to `HTML` then I can click button which sends `POST` requests and I get `POST!` in browser.

```
    def _html(self, message):
        """This just generates an HTML document that includes `message`
        in the body. Override, or re-write this do do more interesting stuff.
        """
        content = f"""<html>
<body>
<h1>{message}</h1>
<form method='POST'>
<button type='submit'>POST</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>"""
        return content.encode("utf8")
```

---

BTW: if you send `POST` with python code then you also get `POST!` - use `print()`

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:8000/', data={'value':True})
print(r.content)
```

but it can't change page in browser. Browser and `requests` are two separated programs (like browser on your computer and browser on my computer) and one can't change page in another (your browser can't change what I can see in my browser)

---

**EDIT:** Full code which I used. I added only `<form>` in content.

```
import argparse
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

    def _html(self, message):
        """This just generates an HTML document that includes `message`
        in the body. Override, or re-write this do do more interesting stuff.
        """
        content = f"""<html>
<body>
<h1>{message}</h1>
<form method='POST'>
<button type='submit'>POST</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>"""
        return content.encode("utf8")  # NOTE: must return a bytes object!

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(self._html("GET!"))

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        # Doesn't do anything with posted data
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(self._html("POST!"))



def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, addr="localhost", port=8000):
    server_address = (addr, port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)

    print(f"Starting httpd server on {addr}:{port}")
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run a simple HTTP server")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-l",
        "--listen",
        default="localhost",
        help="Specify the IP address on which the server listens",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-p",
        "--port",
        type=int,
        default=8000,
        help="Specify the port on which the server listens",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    run(addr=args.listen, port=args.port)
```